# How to form clusters from a list of related ordered pairs (lists)? Please read the details

Tags: python, graph

Suppose we have a list of lists,
`master = [[1,2], [2,5], [3,5], [7,8], [11,8], [11,12]]`
where each ordered-pair is related, meaning **1,2 are related and so are 2,5** and they follow *Transitive* *property*, implies, `1,2,5` belong to the same cluster.

The question is how do we cluster the above list into related elements?

master's clusters would be: 
`{1,2,3,5} and {7,8,11,12}`

I am using Python and thinking in terms of graphs. The efficient, the better.

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let regard the master list as a record of points and edges between them. Which means there are 8 points 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, and 6 edges between them.
Following code may give you what you want.

```
import networkx
from networkx.algorithms.components.connected import connected_components

def to_graph(CL, edge):
    G = networkx.Graph()
    for part in CL:
        G.add_nodes_from(part)
        G.add_edges_from(edge)
    return G

master = [[1,2], [2,5], [3,5], [7,8], [11,8], [11,12]]

G = to_graph(master, master)
for se in connected_components(G):
    print list(se)
```

> [1, 2, 3, 5]
>   [8, 11, 12, 7]

and you can directly have your graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pos = networkx.shell_layout(G)
networkx.draw(G, pos)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Scipy has an implementation of connected components that look suitable for this problem, see [scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components.html).

Comment: would be nice if you added a use case example

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I'm no Python programmer - I don't have an environment installed.